# Get month name, weekday name, or time name convert into date

Tags: php, date

Please help get month name, weekday name, or time name convert into date

Examples

1. My exam on this Monday -> my exam on 20 feb 2017,
2. My exam on next Monday -> my exam on 27 feb 2017
3. My exam was on last Monday -> my exam was on 13 feb 2017
4. My birth day on  second feb 1994 -> my birthday on 13 feb 1994

Comment: The question is very good. And could be better if any effort included. This is kind of Artificial Intelligence. You can define your set of rules for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) function for this:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last monday"));    // 2017-02-13
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("this monday"));    // 2017-02-20
```

Note "this Monday" and "next Monday" are the same thing in English.